# Не корректная загрузка Windows после установки

Tags: windows, загрузка, ос

опишу ситуацию:
Недавно установил Windows 7 на жесткий диск компьютера, попробовал включить, но после включения происходит загрузка системы в безопасном режиме, а не в обычном. Самое интересное, что обои на главном экране есть и при этом нет надписи безопасный режим. В чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить? Заранее спасибо

Comment: И как вы без надписи определяете, что это безопасный режим?

Comment: Мне тоже интересно как? Это что-то новое.

Comment: @andreymal Ну, вообще-то, можно взглянуть через WMI на BootupState. Варианты: Normal boot, Fail-safe boot, Fail-safe with network boot. А иначе как вы, допустим, в скрипте будете ловить зловреда??? В стиле "Взгляните, пожалуйста, на картинку, написано ли там "Безопасный режим"? :)))

Comment: @ViktorTomilov я-то догадываюсь, как можно глянуть, вопрос — глядит ли автор)

Comment: Основное предположение: не встали или коряво встали драйверы для видеокарты. Или встали, но не отконфигурированы (вероятность меньше).